# Position fixed element in position sticky not working on iOS 14

Tags: css, position, ios14

Encountered an issue that is apparently not reported by anyone else;
I am having a modal for a calendar placed on top of everything with `position: fixed` but it's parent is a sticky bar placed with `position: sticky`.

This results in working everywhere, EXCEPT on iOS14 where the display is kept "inline" and is a weird hybrid rendering that looks completely broken.

I tried the usual iOS madness fixes by adding transforms, backface visibility, bla bla bla but none of these changes anything.
Removing the `position: sticky` from the parent fixes everything but removes a feature.

Anyone else encountered this issue? if yes, what was the solve ?
(except from not using `position: sticky` and doing that in JS)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example so we can see this for ourselves.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example